# How to make the children not repeating in ag grid (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am trying to make the child should be 3 columns only it based on `assetCode`
where `PRN`, `PRN1` and `PRN2` should be displayed.

here's the code for list component

***list.component.ts***

```
this.rowData.push(
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 2', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-20 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 3', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-21 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 4', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-22 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 5', 'assetCode': 'PRN 2', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
      },
    );

    this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((item: any) => {
      return format(item.date, 'YYYY') === param;
    });

    const newData: any = [];
    this.rowData.forEach((x: any) => {
      const existing = newData.find((y: any) => format(y.date, 'YYYY-MM') === format(x.date, 'YYYY-MM')
        && y.assetCode === x.assetCode && y.code === x.code);
      if (existing) {
        existing.assetCount += existing.assetCount;
      } else {
        newData.push(x);
        this.rowData = newData;
      }
    });

    this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'code',
        'pinned': 'left',
        'lockPosition': true
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed',
            'valueGetter': ' ', 'headerClass': '', 'cellStyle': {}
          }
        ]
      };

      this.rowData.forEach((key: any) => {
        if (this.monthNames[i].monthName === format(key.date, 'MMMM')) {
          record.children.push(
            {
              'headerName': key.code, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'headerClass': 'header-text-center',
              'cellStyle': { 'justify-content': 'center' },
              'valueGetter': key.assetCount ? key.assetCount.toString() : null
            }
          );
        }
      });
      this.columnDefs.push(record);
    }
    }
```

***output***

[image]

***expected output***

[image]

thanks in advance for helping

[image]

Comment: A stackblitz example would be great, to understand what is happening

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ssnu9 --- @Kenny

Comment: @ABC the example is not working are you sure its loading the table into the view and all imports and node modules are in place for the example to work fine?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dlocv1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS

Comment: its still not rendering the view, and am seeing errors in console, are you sure its working fine for you?

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS sorry sir, it's not working Im new

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS but on my vs its working

Comment: @ABC at least post the columnDefs log (i mean consol.log(this.columnDefs) and post it in your question) it and post it here, there is a error in that field which is causing this error

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS done update sir.

Comment: In your code at what point are you setting PRN, PRN 1 and PRN 2 as headers?... and also from your object my understanding is that, Machine 1 is mapping to first column, Machine 2 to second column... and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203162/discussion-between-abc-and-sri-venkata-pavan-kumar-mhs).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
  (result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: [
      ...(result[item[key]] || []),
      item,
    ],
  }), 
  {},
);
 var list= [{
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 2', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-20 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 3', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-21 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 4', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-22 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 5', 'assetCode': 'PRN 2', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
      }];
      
const grouped = groupBy(list, 'code');
    
//console.log(grouped);
let newArr =[];
for (var key of Object.keys(grouped)) {
let obj ={};
obj["code"] =key;
grouped[key].forEach(function(element){
  //console.log(element);
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(element.assetCode)) 
  { 
    obj[element.assetCode] = 0;
  }
  obj[element.assetCode] = obj[element.assetCode] +element.assetCount;
});
newArr.push(obj);

    
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: how'bout the date sir?

Comment: Do you have any date conditions?